# MYSQL Huge records and find each nearest point

Tags: c#, mysql, performance, bigdata, latitude-longitude

I have some trouble when I come across with MySQL.
I have a table **deviceLog** which store vehicle log consist of:
1. DeviceID
2. dateTime
3. Latitude
4. Longitude

The device will store a log into the Database every minute.
Which mean 1440 records per day for one vehicle.
Assuming I have 5000 vehicles, which will sum up to around 7.2Millions Row of Log Data into the table every day.

Every month I need to generate a Device Location Report of every vehicle.  Which relates to another table name as **POI** (point of interest) which stores:
1. LocationName
2. Latitude
3. Longitude

The final output of the should be:
DeviceID, DateTimer, LocationName (Based on the Latitude,Longitude provided by the **deviceLog**)

For the LocationName, I created a function which Call a Stored Procedure to retrieve it by sending the row's Latitude and Longitude, it will return the LocationName from **POI**  table

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SPGetGeoName`(IN `xLat` DOUBLE, IN `xLon` DOUBLE, OUT `xLocationName` NVARCHAR(1500))
BEGIN

declare lon1 float; declare lon2 float;
    declare lat1 float; declare lat2 float;
    declare dist float; declare pi float;
    set pi = 3.1415926;
    set dist=1.9;
    set lon1 = xLon-dist/abs(cos(radians(xLat))*69);
    set lon2 = xLon+dist/abs(cos(radians(xLat))*69);
    set lat1 = xLat-(dist/69); set lat2 = xLat+(dist/69);

SET xLocationName = (SELECT locationName FROM poiTest 
                WHERE longitude BETWEEN lon1 AND lon2 AND 
                      latitude BETWEEN lat1 AND lat2 AND
                      3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((xLat-latitude)* pi/180 / 2), 2) +COS(xLat*pi/180) * COS(latitude*pi/180) *POWER(SIN((xLon-longitude) * pi /180 / 2), 2) )) < dist 
                      ORDER BY 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((xLat-latitude)* pi/180 / 2), 2) +COS(xLat*pi/180) * COS(latitude*pi/180) *POWER(SIN((xLon-longitude) * pi /180 / 2), 2) )) ASC limit 1);


END
```

The result like 15 seconds per vehicle for 1 month, which will take around 1 day in rough calculate to generate the whole report.

Is there anyway to overcome this issue?

```
CREATE TABLE `deviceLog` (
   `tripID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `latitude` float NOT NULL,
   `longitude` double NOT NULL,
   `rssi` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
   `speed` float NOT NULL,
   `course` float NOT NULL,
   `hdop` float NOT NULL,
   `dateTimer` datetime NOT NULL,
   `gpsStat` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
   `unitStat` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
   `battVolt` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
   `fuelLevel` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `fuelData` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `ignVolt` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
   `odoMeter` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
   `deviceID` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
   `chksum` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
   `resol` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
   `driverID` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `geoFences` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `poiLoc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `eventStat` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `IOStat` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   `groupID` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`tripID`),
   KEY `deviceID` (`deviceID`),
   KEY `dateTimer` (`dateTimer`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3423023 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `poi` (
   `poiID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `locationName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
   `state` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `longitude` float(10,7) DEFAULT NULL,
   `latitude` float DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`poiID`),
   KEY `lat` (`longitude`,`latitude`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=683606 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Comment: how many entries do you have in your POI table?

Comment: Hi Olli, there are around 550,000 of entries.

Comment: although calculation in database is fairly fast, an idea might be to store some of the already precalculated values (where possible) to the tables themselves and use those. It might help at least a bit

Comment: Rather than put an answer I would suggest not using MySQL for this purpose; both because you are going to run into scaling issues, but mainly because there are dedicated tech stacks which were designed for just this kind of use case (IoT / streaming / event data / time series).

Comment: Thanks Olli for the feedback, to fasten up the process, I have precalculated the data everyday, for instance: all data dated before 3/10/2018, will be processed to update their location.

Comment: Thanks Jens for the feedback, as you mentioned that there are dedicated tech stacks for huge data.  I read some posts from other forum stating that for Huge DB, we need to use another DB application purely for Read Data because Read queries will kill the application. You need massive cache systems to work during scaling.
I most probably will take a look on how others big website like Youtube on how they overcome it.

Comment: YouTube - no.  See what I added to my Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "dedicated stacks", they mean lots of servers.  Think cost.

There are several things that can be done without throwing hardware at it.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table; meanwhile, I will assume you have no (or useless) indexes.  I'll check the datatypes to see what can be shrunk -- to save disk space and some time.

I don't like the wide range of precisions being used -- `DOUBLE` has 16 significant digits; `69` has only 2.  Consider `69.172`.  See the `RADIAN` function in place of an 8-digit pi/180.

`dist/abs(cos(radians(xLat))*69)` could be evaluated once (for a tiny speedup)

`ABS()` is probably unnecessary.

Without an index, the query will scan the entire table.  At least have `INDEX(latitude)` and `INDEX(longitude)`.  That would change the effort from 550K tests to perhaps 2K.  To shrink it down to perhaps 30, you would need a significant rewrite, al a http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng

Probably half the time a 'device' is 'at' the same 'location'.  (This is especially true of vehicles.)  In that case, *start* by seeing if the device has not moved since it was last located.

That brings up another issue -- Don't store a location unless it has moved significantly.  That would save half the disk space.

Another thought -- Change the customer's expectations.  Don't locate the device every minute, but only every 10 minutes.  This, alone, would change the compute time from 1 day to 2.4 hours.

Comments on schema:

- `FLOAT` takes 4 bytes; can they be turned into some smaller datatype?  lat/lng are inconsistent.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices) for some choices.
- What are `geoFences` and `resol`?
- Don't use (m,n) with FLOAT (eg float(10,7)).

If you will be fetching all the data for one device at a time, then change

```
PRIMARY KEY (`tripID`),
KEY `deviceID` (`deviceID`),
```

to

```
PRIMARY KEY (`deviceID`, tripID),
KEY (`tripID`),
```

This will better take advantage of "clustering".  But you must also change to InnoDB.

You will need to eliminate 'duplicate' entries when the device is stopped.  Else, you will have disk space trouble (and performance problems).

Not like YouTube

YouTube has different issues; ditto for most of the other biggies.  Don't bother studying them.

I suggest that your number one problem is data volume.

- Fewer columns.
- Fewer rows.
- Summarize information.

24 columns -- Some of them don't change for for minutes, or for all day.  So, don't store them all the time.

Split up the 24 columns.  What is the main query?  How *few* columns are needed to support it?  That is, build *up* the table from 0 columns; you will make more progress faster than trying to cut back from 24 columns.

One row every 15 seconds.  Even when the 'device' is turned off?  There's a huge savings.

Recalculate the name of the city the device is in?  But it is *usually* in the same city as last time.  Check for that *first*.  That should save a lot of CPU time.

Use a 3-byte `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` for the 'city'.  That's what `poiID` should be, not a 4-byte `INT SIGNED`.  The `JOIN` will be cheap enough when you display the name.

Aging out.  Sure the customer needs yesterday's details.  But maybe last month's data could be courser?  And last year's even less detailed -- perhaps even tossed?

If you will be tossing 'old' data, now is the time to `PARTITION` the table. so that purging will be 'instantaneous'.

Etc. Etc.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for your feedback, however customer expectations can't be lower down as the market currently has offered device tracking every 30 seconds > 10 seconds.
I added the SHOW CREATE TABLE for the both relevant tables being used in the reporting on my first post.

Comment: I added to my Answer.

Comment: Hi Rick, 
1. let me figure out is the impact of turning into smaller datatype.
2. geoFences and resol are useless may ignore it.
3. Ok noted.
4. i have change the primary key, it has fasten by 0.01 second per 400k data.
5. I agree that duplicate entries is the main issue right now, i will figure out how to remove the duplicate, by the Odometer + Lat Lng.
6. I try another approach which is table per device, because all device log are centralized, I thinking to split the log back to each individual log to fasten up the process, so other users will not be affected by other huge data device.

Comment: @ArthurLiew - Even if those columns are empty or NULL, they are taking 2 bytes per row.  So consider dropping them.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for the info, I will discuss with my team about this info and the impact of it.  Appreciate for sharing knowledge to me.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Rick, eventually i opt for another alternative solution.  I split the deviceLog into Device per Table.  Anyway, every night we will preprocess the raw data into useful data for reporting and stored it into the DeviceTable.  

The DeviceTable consist of the poiLocation which is the most time consuming in the formula.  I understand this is a just a temporary solution, however I think this is the least impact towards the overall system.